# an old shed has wiring

Tags: wiring, gfci

I just wanted to confirm any safety hazards or possible fixes. I moved into a home that has 12/2 gauge wire going under the house to a shed on the other side of the house, so it's stretching the 12/2 wire about 20 foot and it's ran in some PVC piping. In the shed itself there is a GFCI weatherized receptacle protecting 2 other 20A receptacles and a light switch with fixture.

I guess my question is, is the 12/2 gauge wire going to harm any power tools in the shed that use 15A? This is because it is stretched farther than recommended and ran in PVC pipe.

It also has a 20 amp breaker, I'm concerned about the length of the 12/2 wire and no breaker panel in the shed as a shut off, I guess the GFCI is a shut off, but how dangerous is this , and should I run new 10/2 wire

Comment: Is that actual PVC *pipe* that was used, or a proper PVC *conduit*?  Also, what kind of cable is the 12/2, and is that the only circuit feeding the shed?

Comment: Romex cable ran through it all, and its regular pvc pipe, it comes out from underneath the house to go into the shed, I feel like it needs re don't with 10/2 wire to a breaker panel in the shed with conduit and wire that's rated for wet conditions, im just not sure on being under the house and in pvc ... what the dangers become

Comment: Yes there's only one 20 amp in the main breaker box feeding to the 3 outlets in the shed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said how long the cable is, so you might want to punch your numbers into a [voltage drop calculator](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm) and see what you get for voltage drop.

Your power tools that have a 15A plug are likely only 12A, so use those numbers.  Most likely you are fine.

You are using "Romex" informally to describe all jacketed multiconductor cable. There are a variety of types and some of them are correct for wet locations, and others are not.  You need to be using a "wet location rated" type for the section that is outdoors.

It is a fact of life that any conduit installed outdoors will most likely be full of water at least some of the time. That is why to use wet-location cable, it is made for that.

Comment: It's about 20 feet long to the first gfci

Comment: 12 AWG cable is more than plenty.  You'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

GFCIs are always good anywhere there is a water source.  And yes, it is a shutoff.  In your case it sounds like it would only trip if internally a wire touched a grounded case of one of your tools.  If it controls all the outlets then obviously they would all go off at the same time.

You mention a PVC pipe.  It is crucial that those be installed properly so there is no chance of moisture getting in.  A photo would help.

Romex is rated for moisture, yes, but not for being submerged.